# Create PDA with no data in it

Tags: anchor, pda

I want to create PDA with no data in it, only SOL balance is needed. Reading following questions ([q1](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/how-do-i-make-a-pda-own-a-system-account), [q2](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/sign-pda-owned-by-system-program)) I found out that I need to create `System Account PDA`, but I am having trouble to implement this with anchor. Some small example how to create and use it would be appreciated.

There are some question that comes using `System Account PDA`:

- In instruction context, `System Account PDA` should be specified as [SystemAccount](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/system_account/struct.SystemAccount.html)?
- Would program be able to withdraw SOL from `System Account PDA` and ensure that the program is the only account that withdraw SOL?
- When calling the transaction that withdraw SOL from `System Account PDA`, `signers` are not required since it's PDA and there is no private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a PDA with an empty account struct. For example

```
pub struct Example<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [..],
        bump,
        payer = ..,
        space = 8,
    )]
    empty_pda: Account<'info, Empty>  
}
#[account]
pub struct Empty {}
```

1. No. An Account<'info> is what you should use.
2. Yes a program will be able to withdraw sol from the PDA. By default, making the PDA a program account(as is done above) ensures that only the program can sign withdrawals from that PDA.
3. Correct, signers are not required for a PDA in the client-side because PDAs have no private key and it's impossible for them to sign that way. [Here's](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/how-to-withdraw-sol-from-a-pda) a link that shows how to withdraw sol from a PDA.

Comment: I was thinking of this solution, but I was confused and thought there may be a better solution.